# jQuery - Prevent submit inside promise with post ajax validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, promise

We trying to stop form submit after an validation returned from an post. The call is inside a promise and after a confirm dialog.

After hours breaking my mind I couldn't make it work.

```
var $form = $('#frmBoleto');

$form.submit(function(e){
    var modo = $('input[name="modo"]:checked').val();

    if (modo == 'naoimprime'){
        // Send post
        $.when( $.post($form.attr('action') + '?verifica', $form.serialize())).then(function( d ){
            if (d && d.exists){
                var answer = window.confirm('You sure?');

                if (!answer){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Form is always submited, why?

Comment: Because ajax is async. The ajax callback (the part with `e.preventDefault()`) doesn't execute until after the form submit handler has finished running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$post().then(...)` callback fires in a later event thread, therefore too late to prevent form submission.

You need to inhibit form submission unconditionally in the `.submit()` handler, and force submission conditionally in the `.then()` callback.

```
var $form = $('#frmBoleto');

$form.submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if ($('input[name="modo"]:checked').val() == 'naoimprime') {
        $.post($form.attr('action') + '?verifica', $form.serialize()).then(function(d) {
            if (d && d.exists && window.confirm('You sure?')) {
                $form.get(0).submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I made this, but using $form.trigger('submit') that calls the same callback again and again...

Comment: I think you need to call `$form.off('submit', <yourhandler>)` before you call `.submit()`

Answer (score -2):

Return **false** in onsubmit event method.